# How do you derive the passphrase from hexadecimal wep key?

Tags: networking, security, wifi

I have a hexadecimal WEP key in the setting of my router.

When I try to connect, the system asks me for the WEP *passphrase*.

**How can I derive it from my *hexadecimal*?**

This is what I have:

```
84:12:7D:13:4D:08:31:89:A4:AF:97:07:21
```

What is the way to get it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Windows will also accept the hexadecimal key, no conversion is needed. In fact, it is the recommended format. From the [documentation for configuring WEP in Windows XP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457016.aspx):

> If you are typing the WEP key using hexadecimal digits, you must type 10 hexadecimal digits for a 40-bit key and 26 hexadecimal digits for a 104-bit key. If you have the choice of the format of the WEP key, choose hexadecimal.

However, you should type `84127D134D083189A4AF970721`, without the `:` characters. Those are just separators which are not actually part of the key.

Finally, note that your key is now useless for security as you have published it on the internet.

Comment: What Windows accepts is irrelevant on this site.

Comment: @Gilles: the OP [cross-posted to Yahoo answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110124021038AAgYKC3), where he mentions that "windows asks me for a pass-phrase". From that I knew that it wasn't really a question about unix/linux. Perhaps I should have mentioned this in my answer.